# Dynamic creating of AR models

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm working with application where identical data store in different tables

Example

```
Items
Items201101
Items201102
Items201103
.....
```

Every month I need to create 1 more table `Items#{year}#{month}` and copy to it data from  Items and I do it with 
`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("insert into  ... select from ... ");`

How can I dynamicly create models for such kind of tables ?
Also If I can do it , How can I remove such models from application scope when such table is dropped ?

Comment: This sounds like the same model but with a different table association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If models are really similar, I would suggest using `eval`. Consider this code:

```
['Bar', 'Baz'].each do |k|
  eval %{
    class Foo#{k}
      def initialize
        puts 'hello from ' + self.class.name
      end
    end
  }
end

FooBar.new
FooBaz.new
```